# Corona sdk prevent x movement of ball

Tags: game-physics, coronasdk

I'm having trouble with preventing a ball from starting to move after It has jumped on a Ractangle. The rectangle is moving with a constant speed to the left. The ball follows the screen. When the ball jumps on the rectangle it gains speed from falling of the rectangle. Pleace help!

Here is some of my code:

```
--make a box
local box1 = display.newRect( 600, 220, 20, 20 )
box1:setFillColor(255,255,255)
physics.addBody( box1, "static", { friction=0, bounce=0.0 } )

-- make a ball (off-screen) and position it
local ball = display.newImage( "ball.png", 20, 20 )
ball.x, ball.y = 100, 200


-- add physics to the ball
physics.addBody( ball, { density = 1.0, friction = 0, bounce = 0, radius = 19 } )

--rotate the ball
local function rotateBall()
ball.rotation = -365
transition.to( ball, { time=1000, rotation=365, onComplete=rotateBall} )

end
rotateBall()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly

- you're trying to make the ball keep rotating infinitely in to-and-fro direction
- make the ball bounce

The code below will work for that:

```
local physics=require("physics")
physics.start()

--make a box
local box1 = display.newRect( 50, 420, 150, 150 )
box1:setFillColor(255,255,255)
physics.addBody( box1, "static", { friction=0, bounce=0.0 } )

-- make a ball (off-screen) and position it
local ball = display.newImage( "scnGame_bird.png", 20, 20 )
ball.x, ball.y = 100, 200


-- add physics to the ball
physics.addBody( ball, { density = 1.0, friction = 0, bounce = 0.8, radius = 19 } )

--rotate the ball

--ball.rotation = -365
local rotateBallReverse
local function rotateBall()
    transition.to( ball, { time=1000, rotation=365, onComplete=rotateBallReverse} )
end

rotateBallReverse = function()
    transition.to( ball, { time=1000, rotation=-365, onComplete=rotateBall} )
end
rotateBall()
```

For the rest, what do you mean by 'prevent x movement'?

Comment: Sorry, I thats not what I was wondering about. What I did was this:  

 -- A per-frame event to move the elements
 local tPrevious = system.getTimer()
 local function move(event)
  --prevent velocity/movement of the ball
  vx, vy = ball:getLinearVelocity() 
  if vx < 0 then
   ball:setLinearVelocity( 0, 0)
   
  end
  
  if vx > 0 then
   ball:setLinearVelocity( 0, 0)
 
  end
 end
 -- Start everything moving
 Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", move );

What it does is check the velocity of the ball for each frame, if its more or less than 0 it's set back too 0.